# How to update an object if any exception while deleting it in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a deleting function that would update an object if present in another object.
In my example, I am deleting items from a bill so I would like to rename the item as "deleted" if hibernate throws a persistence exception.

What I tried initially was:

```
 public boolean delete(T entity) {
    LOGGER.info("I want to delete: " + entity);
    try {
        getCurrentSession().remove(entity);
        getCurrentSession().flush();
    }catch (PersistenceException exception){
        LOGGER.error("returning false");
        getCurrentSession().update(entity);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

I am getting

> org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to update()

I imagine that's because I need to get the current session closed and work on another one, so I tried:

```
public boolean delete(T entity) {
    LOGGER.info("I want to delete: " + entity);
    try {
        getCurrentSession().remove(entity);
        getCurrentSession().flush();
    }catch (PersistenceException exception){
        LOGGER.error("returning false");
        session.close();
        session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        getCurrentSession().update(entity);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

But it gives me

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active

I tried to use a second transaction instead of reusing the same but end up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it!
The above code was from my DAO and I used @Transactionnal in my business logic, so I simply added

> @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)

to my deleting method in there and had it working